# Create a list from a char and remove an element in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have written the following function that gets a char, creates a list by a specified length of a char from it, and finally removes an element from the newly created list.

```
def create_list_from_char(char, remove_elem):
            n = int(len(remove_elem))
            my_list = [char[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(char), n)]           
            print("Created list is: ", my_list)
            print(remove_elem in my_list)
            new_list = my_list.remove(remove_elem)
            print("new list is: ", new_list)
            return new_list
```

However, when I try it it seems it is not removing the specified element from the listand it returns None. Here is an example:

```
>>> create_list_from_char('ABCDEFGHIJKL', 'IJKL')
Created list is:  ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL']
True
new list is:  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
def create_list_from_char(char, remove_elem):
            n = int(len(remove_elem))
            my_list = [char[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(char), n)]           
            print("Created list is: ", my_list)
            print(remove_elem in my_list)
            my_list.remove(remove_elem)
            print("new list is: ", my_list)
            return my_list
```

the output:

```
>>> create_list_from_char('ABCDEFGHIJKL', 'IJKL')
Created list is:  ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL']
True
new list is:  ['ABCD', 'EFGH']
['ABCD', 'EFGH']
```

### More info

the `remove` method deletes the selected item from the original list and won't return a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`list.remove` is a method that does a deletion in-place and doesn't return a new list